# Multiply the values between two columns in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(day,SD.STARTDATE,SD.ENDDATE) AS TotalDays ,amount 
FROM staydetails
```

For example, the amount column may have a value of `100`, I need to multiply the value of `totaldays` and `amount` and add the result to another column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the computed column to your select list, like so:

```
 select  
 DATEDIFF(day,SD.STARTDATE,SD.ENDDATE) AS TotalDays ,
 amount,
 (DATEDIFF(day,SD.STARTDATE,SD.ENDDATE) * amount) AS CalculatedAmount
from staydetails
```

Note that you will need to repeat the `DATEDIFF` function - you cannot use the alias TotalDays.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straight forward:

```
select  DATEDIFF(day,SD.STARTDATE,SD.ENDDATE) AS TotalDays ,amount,
        (DATEDIFF(day,SD.STARTDATE,SD.ENDDATE) * amount) as Result 
from staydetails
```

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply them like so:

```
select  DATEDIFF(day,SD.STARTDATE,SD.ENDDATE) AS TotalDays ,
        amount ,
        DATEDIFF(day,SD.STARTDATE,SD.ENDDATE) * amount AS CalculatedValue
from staydetails
```

You may have tried to reference `TotalDays` like so: `TotalDays * amount`, but you have to perform the calculation on the underlying value, which is the result of the `DATEDIFF` calculation rather than the alias column name.