# Multiply two columns into 3rd column while one fo them is count(*) in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I did manipulation on table using the group by functions and count(*):

```
SELECT TOP 10000 
  [column1]
  ,[column2]
  ,[column3]
  ,count(*) as counts
FROM TableX
group by column1, column2,column3
```

my result is table that looks:

```
column1 | column2 | column2 | Counts
------------------------------------        
   X1   |    X2   |    X3   |   X4
   X5   |    X6   |    X7   |   X8
   ...
```

Now How can I add an additional column which will present the result of X3 * X4, X7 * X8 etc.?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiply the values between two columns in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451730/multiply-the-values-between-two-columns-in-sql)

Comment: `X3` seems to be a varchar, how do you want to multiply strings?

Answer (score 1):

If it's actually SQL-Server not MySQL you can use following:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT TOP 10000 
       [column1]
      ,[column2]
      ,[column3]
      ,counts = count(*)  OVER (PARTITION BY column1, column2,column3)
      ,RN = row_number(*) OVER (PARTITION BY column1, column2,column3 Order By column1, column2,column3)
    FROM TableX
)
SELECT  [column1]
       ,[column2]
       ,[column3]
       ,counts
       ,Product1 = column3 * counts, 
       ...
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the result from your query, and then multiply:

```
select  [column1], [column2], [column3], counts, [column3] * counts
from
(
SELECT TOP 10000 
  [column1]
  ,[column2]
  ,[column3]
  ,count(*) as counts
FROM TableX
group by column1, column2,column3
)
```